# Google Chrome: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 407 (Proxy Authentication Required)

Tags: google-chrome, proxy, lan, http-status-code-407

I'm connecting to the internet using a Proxy server. I already set the manual proxy setup with my IP address and the port. Now the issue is when I'm browsing on the internet chrome requires proxy username and password. I remember my proxy username and password but to enter those the popup window is not popping up. In Console I have this error and browser window is keep refreshing continuously with blank window.

[image]

Is there any way I can give proxy server username and password from Chrome settings? This happens only in chrome non incognito mode. I tried with Incognito mode, it asks the proxy username and password and thereafter everything working perfectly,

[image]

Note: This was listed in 2009 as a bug but I didn't found any solution to this https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6666

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no answer over the internet, I will post the way I solved the issue. Actually this is not the proper way to solve the issue but at least you can connect to the internet using this method.

*Proxy authentication details are stored some ware in your chrome account which associated with your email.* After struggling few hours, what I did was, **login to the chrome with another email** so here it wont affect the settings on the previous Gmail account. Thereafter it asks the proxy username and password.

Note: Don't click the `Never` button if dialogue box pops up and ask to store the username and password.

I hope this will help for someone in future.